# How to set the trigger in Editable Email Notification in Configuration Slicing plugin?

Tags: email, configuration, jenkins-plugins

I have more than 100 builds running in Jenkins and I want to set the trigger for email to **Status Changed** to all of them using Configuration Slicing plugin. I am able to do it for each one of them individually through Editable email notification in **Post Build Actions**. Can someone please help me to configure it in **Configuration Slicing plugin** with the trigger as **Status Changed**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this:

You can set a template for Editable Email Notification. You need to install the plugin for the same. 
You can configure the template as per your needs.
After you have created the template, in Configuration Slicing you need to assign the plugin name to the jobs that require it.